# Add to Muon "software sources" from command line (not JUST to apt sources.list.d)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, muon-package-manager

I added some apt sources (postgres, docker) to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, I can install docker and postgresql-15 without any issues.

When I open `Discover`, I see the sources that are also in apt.
However when I open Muon, I don't see these sources.

How can I make sure these sources are also present in Muon without adding them manually? Is it possible to add them through the command line?